# Using PIL modifying and then saving a TIFF returns error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

TLDR; I'm trying to take a TIFF, resize it, then save it. However it returns an error. This works fine if I change the saved filetype to png or jpg.

System: Windows 7
Tried using both Python 3.4 and 2.7.

Code:

```
from PIL import Image

try:                                               #test file exists
    im = Image.open(r"c:\temp\file.tif")
except:
    print("Error opening image")

multiply = 5                                       #how much bigger
processing = tuple([multiply*x for x in im.size])  #maths
saved = (r"c:\temp\biggerfile.tif")               #save location

imB = im.resize((processing))                      #resizing

imB.save(saved)                                    #saving
```

I need to resize a TIFF because I'm using tesseract-ocr, and resizing the image to get a better output. The program seems to work best with a TIFF.

The error I receive is:

```
_TIFFVSetField: c:\temp\biggerfile.tif: Bad value 2 for "ExtraSamples" tag.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "step1.py", line 15, in <module>
    imB.save(saved)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1684, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1185, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, 'libtiff', a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 430, in _getencoder
    return encoder(mode, *args + extra)
RuntimeError: Error setting from dictionary
```

Thanks!

Comment: This code works for me.  The only thing I can think of is either you don't have a proper encoder for tiffs or maybe it's tripping up on the `.tif`.  Have you tried changing it to `.tiff` in your filenames?  On linux it does just fine with the `.tif`, but you never know.  The error is occurring when you save, and a method called `_getencoder` is trying to return invalid data, so I would assume it has something to do with the filename or the encoder.

Comment: I'm doing this on windows, but I have tried both 3.4 and 2.7. I have tried using .tiff and the filename without the extension and "TIF".

Comment: I think the error points to [unassociated alpha data](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/extrasamples.html). Can PIL re-save the image right after loading (before resizing) as a tif? Maybe you try to get rid of this data that trips up PIL.

Comment: you can try using pillow instead of PIL,https://pillow.readthedocs.org/

Comment: first off, yep, always use pillow instead of PIL.

Comment: I've tried this on windows and also works fine. My test file is *.tif. I do use Pillow instead of PIL, looks like i might be something related to that.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that there are multiple good alternative options for reading/writing TIFFs in Python. See this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76937/45164

Comment: As a side note, it's [issue #1227](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1227) on Pillow, which was fixed a few months ago. Using a *recent* version of Pillow thus solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install libtiff
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1185, in _save
e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, 'libtiff', a, im.encoderconfig)
```

Looks like that's the error that is holding you  up. It's trying to access libtiff and you don't have it installed so it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, when using PIL to combine multiple images to one and adding a label.
I could fix this easily by converting the .tif file to a .png file in MS Paint (pls don't hate me for using MS :D). Quality of the final merged image was not reduced.