# Split Multipage Tiff file and save each frame/page as a Tiff

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

Using Python, I am trying to import a multipage tiff file, split it by its page/frame and then save each of the pages as tiff files.

There are 2 methods that I have gotten relatively close to my desired outcome with but they both seem to fail when it comes to saving the split page as tiff.

METHOD 1:

```
from PIL import Image
    
currentFileName = "image.tif"
currentRevisedFullFileName = "/dbfs/mnt/temp/"+currentFileName
im = Image.open(currentRevisedFullFileName)
numberOfFrames = img.n_frames
           
for i in range(numberOfFrames):
  im.seek(i)
  im.save('page_%s.tif'%(i,))
```

METHOD 2:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

currentFileName = "image.tif"
currentRevisedFullFileName = "/dbfs/mnt/temp/"+currentFileName
im = Image.open(currentRevisedFullFileName)

for j, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
  pageTifFileName = currentFileName.split(".")[0] + "-" + str(j+1).zfill(3) + ".TIF"
  pageTifPathName = "/dbfs/mnt/temp/" + pageTifFileName
  page.save(pageTifPathName, "Tiff")
```

The second method works perfectly if I replace the suffix of the file name from ".TIF" to ".jpg" and save it with the "Jpeg" format. However, when I try to save it as a Tiff as in the code above, I get an error pointing to the "page.save()" line of code.

For both methods, I am getting an "RuntimeError: Error setting from dictionary" error.

Any input on what modifications I can make to the .save params for the tiff files to save?

full traceback

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
last) <command-3375652163217349in <module>
      4   print("i = {} and tif file name = {}".format(i, tiff_file))
      5   print("tiff_file = {}".format(tiff_file))
----> 6   splitTif(tiff_file)

<command-3558528313119511in splitTif(currentFileName)
     10       im.seek(i)
     11       print("i = {} imgSeek = {} at position {}".format(i, im.seek(i), im.tell()))
---> 12       im.save('page_%s.tif'%(i,))
     13     except EOFError:
     14       print("EXCEPTION = {}".format(EOFError))

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in
save(self, fp, format, **params)    2170     2171         try:
-> 2172             save_handler(self, fp, filename)    2173         finally:    2174             # do what we can to clean up

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py
in _save(im, fp, filename)    1638         tags.sort()    1639        
a = (rawmode, compression, _fp, filename, tags, types)
-> 1640         e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, "libtiff", a, im.encoderconfig)    1641         e.setimage(im.im, (0, 0) + im.size) 
1642         while True:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in
_getencoder(mode, encoder_name, args, extra)
    449     except AttributeError as e:
    450         raise OSError(f"encoder {encoder_name} not available") from e
--> 451     return encoder(mode, *args + extra)
    452 
    453 

RuntimeError: Error setting from dictionary
```

Comment: Can't (re)produce any error for a (minimized) version of method 1. Loading a local multi page TIFF file, and saving all pages as TIFF files works without any problems. Please provide the full stack trace to your errors.

Comment: Hi HansHires - I added the traceback to the post. The Tiff files I am working with are documents.

Comment: Do you have `libtiff` installed? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620076/using-pil-modifying-and-then-saving-a-tiff-returns-error/31106778

Comment: Running print(features.check('libtiff')) returns True so it is installed.

Comment: I believe the issue has to do with specific tags on my tif files. Like tag 269 which returns "('\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', )". I've tried removing some non-baseline tags but still get the same error when trying to save as tiff.

Answer (score 1):

The `tifftools` python library can do this.  It can be run as a command-line tool (`tifftools split <input file>`), or from python:

```
import tifftools

info = tiff_tools.read_tiff(<input file>)
for ifd in info['ifds']:
  tifftools.write_tiff(ifd, <output path>)
```

This library will keep all of the tags associated with each image in the tiff file and will not recompress the image in any way.

So, with your code as the base, this would be:

```
import tifftools

currentFileName = "image.tif"
currentRevisedFullFileName = "/dbfs/mnt/temp/"+currentFileName
info = tifftools.read_tiff(currentRevisedFullFileName)
for i, ifd in enumerate(info['ifds']):
  tifftools.write_tiff(ifd, 'page_%s.tif'%(i,))
```

disclaimer: I am the author of `tifftools`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the code but no files were saved so I updated the last line of code to include the output path: tifftools.write_tiff(ifd, currentRevisedFullFileName+"page_%s.tif"%(i,))

This gave me a "OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported" error.

Comment: Error 95 is usually a permission error.  Do you have write permissions and enough file space in the local directory?